# htaccess redirect doesn't work: Too many redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

How we can redirect an old URL with `//` to have only one `/`

From:

```
https://www.example.com/maincategory//subcategory/
```

To:

```
https://www.example.com/maincategory/subcategory/
```

This solution has too many redirects:

```
Redirect 301 /maincategory//subcategory/ /maincategory/subcategory/
```

Comment: Can you include what you have now for what you're matching and what you've tried, how it doesn't work, etc?

Comment: @Sloloem All those elements were already included in the question. (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite to do this. Try the following, at the top of the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^GET /maincategory//subcategory/"
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

This uses the "feature" that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* has already had multiple slashes reduced. We then redirect back to this same URL-path using the `$1` backreference. The redirect loop is prevented by checking that the actual URL requested contains the double slash (as stored in the `THE_REQUEST` server variable).

`THE_REQUEST` server variable contains the first line of the HTTP request headers. And, importantly, is not *processed*.

Note that I've omitted the end-of-string anchor (`$`), so the above will match `/maincategory//subcategory/<anything>` and redirect accordingly. If you specifically want to only match `/maincategory//subcategory/` then include a *space* (although *space* + "HTTP" is easier to read) at the end of the *CondPattern*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^GET /maincategory//subcategory/ HTTP"
```

Clear your browser cache before testing. Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues.

> This solution has too many redirects:
>
> ```
> Redirect 301 /maincategory//subcategory/ /maincategory/subcategory/
> ```

It would seem that Apache reduces multiple slashes in *both* the requested URL-path and the URL-path supplied to the `Redirect` directive before matching, so you end up with a redirect loop.